# Is this inscription in the Jefferson memorial consistent with Jefferson's views?

Tags: slavery, jefferson

An inscription inside the Jefferon memorial says: ---
God who gave us life gave us Liberty. Can the liberties of a nation be secure when we have removed a conviction that these liberties are the gift of God? Indeed I tremble for my country when I reflect that God is just, that his justice cannot sleep forever. Commerce between master and slave is depotism. Nothing is more certainly written in the book of fate than that these people are to be free establish the law for educating the common people. This is the business of the state to effect and on a general plan. ----
Would Jefferson have said that? He was a slave owner himself.

Comment: He didn't say slavery is despotism, he said commerce between master and slave is despotism. Antislavery and anti capitalism are not the same

Answer (score 2):

The official story is that the inscription is [taken](http://socialenquiry.org/socialepistemics.com/AD_book_extracts/excerpts/jeffersons_monumental_quote.html) from Jefferson’s Notes on the State of Virginia, with the last two sentences being from a letter to George Washington. [A manuscript](http://memory.loc.gov/cgi-bin/ampage?collId=mtj1&fileName=mtj1page001.db&recNum=320).

The quote isn't some black-and-white assertion against slavery. Thomas Jefferson had complex and evolving relationships with slaves. He owned lots of them (inherited some 135 of them), had a romantic relationship with one of them after his wife died (including kids), waived various fees, and was the key politician who banned importation of new slaves and then slavery itself in numerous states.

It's just wrong to assume that a politician in the late 18th century should have behaved and acted like a radical social justice warrior in the 21st century. There is no contradiction between Jefferson's life and the inscription and Jefferson was an amazing politician and president who has improved the U.S. society dramatically.

Comment: It is also very wrong to whitewash history and dispose of any critical evaluation as something only “radical social justice warriors” would do. In particular, much has been written about Jefferson's relationship with Sally Hemings and presenting as a “romantic relationship” (and evidence of a complex relationship with slaves?!) is a questionable choice of words. Besides, this hardly seems to address the question.

Comment: I am just saying that those who "critically evaluate" either completely misunderstand the history or deliberately distort it while they attempt to intimidate people at the present and reach their own goals. Slavery was as old as the human civilizations themselves - and slavery has done a huge amount of good stuff for the mankind. It's only a recent fad to pretend that slavery is a bad crime from all viewpoints. And the people who are saying these things today are both deluded and not courageous - they really face no risks for saying these silly things. My answer surely addresses the question.

Comment: None of the contemporary people similar to you who would love to "critically evaluate"  has done more than 0.00001% of what Jefferson has done for the societal progress. They are just a bunch of hypocrites pretending to be good people although there are absolutely no facts or deeds that could back such claims.

Comment: Well, that's even worse than I thought, your comments just confirm that you have zero interest in a history or the question itself and just were itching to rant on the subject. Also why this obsession with what's good or bad, what I personally think or whether I face personal risks? All this seem to have no place in a rational approach to history and I don't think you need to be a “radical social justice warrior” to disagree with it.

Comment: I am used to occasionally get a minus vote from an ignorant, ideologically blinded individual. You're automatically forgiven. The rating system on the server isn't perfect but it is better than nothing. But could you please stop flooding this page with your values that have nothing to do with the historical question at the top? The question was whether Jefferson said those things, the answer is Yes, and he also had quite some credentials and reasons to say similar things.

Comment: You seem desperate to turn this into a political debate and obsessed with my “values” (of which I said nothing). What I object to is in fact the deeply ahistorical and ideological nature of your comments. Surely, if you are “used“ to get minus votes, maybe you are doing something wrong?

Comment: I am exactly the one who doesn't want any political debate here. I had to refer to the present because it was needed to explain a misunderstanding by the OP - his incorrect assumption that a slaveowner couldn't have dared to offer his opinions about slavery. The misunderstanding follows from an intentional poisoning and silencing of the public debate by people like you. If people like you weren't poisoning the discourse in this way, people would understand that there is absolute no contradiction between Jefferson's life and the inscription.

Comment: Look, at the physics stack exchange, I am the 2nd highest reputation user, but even there, I am used to negative votes and I don't protest and I know and pretty much everyone knows that the IQ of the downvoters is some 30 points below mine in average. This simply sometimes happens. One can't expect moderators to automatically remove everyone similar to you who is causing chaos and problems that are illegitimate according to the purpose of the server. I am not writing the answer to you (not interested in Jefferson) - I am writing it to enrich the mankind, those who will search for such answers.

Comment: Some easy questions then (certainly for someone with such a yuge IQ): Why make evidence-free assumptions about the nature of the relationship between Hemings and Jefferson if you are interested in historical facts rather than making those facts more palatable to contemporary sensitivities? Why bring up “radical cultural warriors” or talk so much about what's good or not if you really want to steer clear of politics? And also, why constantly insult me or try to ascribe opinions to me?

Comment: Also, how do a couple of comments amount to “silencing the public debate“? Funny how you just admitted not to be interested in Jefferson, it just confirms you were trying to bait people into a debate about political correctness and waiting for an occasion to post some ideological rant.

Comment: `None of the contemporary people similar to you who would love to "critically evaluate" has done more than 0.00001% of what Jefferson has done` --> This is a straw man argument. It is like saying that only a scientist with the credentials of Einstein can talk, test and improve Einstein's theories. So you understand your negative votes. And by the same rule, you would not be entitled to answer the question, neither.

Comment: It is outrageous that this complete and well documented answer was voted down. Something is definitely wrong with this site.

Comment: +1 You are correct. People today cannot understand these ideas.